# Erdas mosaic producing lots of black space?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, erdas-imagine, image-mosaic

I am trying to create an imagery mosaic using erdas imagine. The original files were in a 16 bit DIM Pan-Sharpened format, which produced a completely unusable blank raster (likely an issue with color balancing). I used ArcMap to turn every image into a 8 bit JP2, but that produced images with lots of black space in order to create rectangles, rather than rhombi. The problem being, is that erdas did not clip out any of the empty space when it was mosaicking. The only possible solution I can think of would be to produce the seamlines in Arc, then use those same seamlines to clip with in erdas in a shapefile. When I tried to load the shapefile into the erdas mosaic tool, it produced an error. Has anybody else dealt with this problem, and is there an easier way that simply clipping and mosaicking one by one in ArcGIS?